# Execute a Batch File (.bat) from a PHP script

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a php code to send SMS from a dongle. It simply takes the two arguments; a phone number & a message and passes it to a .bat file.

```
$phoneNo = +1234567890;

$SMSMesseage = "your message";
$SMSMsg = "\"$SMSMesseage\"";

exec("sendsms.bat $phoneNo $SMSMsg");
```

I'm using Gammu tool to configure and send the sms through the dongle. So the .bat file contains below code'

```
echo on
::
echo
::
cd C:\<installation_path>\Gammu 1.33.0\bin
set phnNo=%1
set msg=%2

gammu -c smsdrc
gammu -c smsdrc --sendsms TEXT %phnNo% -text %msg%
```

So, my issue is, when I'm accessing the sendSmsPhp.php through the web browser, it sends the sms without any issue. But when I trying to make it as Windows task scheduler it is not working.

I tried to execute the php script directly through the command prompt using below command;

```
c:\<path_to_xampp>\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:\<path_to_xampp>\xampp\htdocs\LIMS_15\sendSmsPhp.php
```

But it returns;

```
'sendsms.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any way to make it happen?

Comment: you could put all the code in the bat file in php

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell cmd to run the batch file

```
exec("cmd sendsms.bat $phoneNo $SMSMsg");
```

Comment: I did the changes and it didn't work. When I tried with direct command on command prompt it didn't return anything.

Comment: Then I am sorry I cannot provide any more advice.  :)